# i am getting this error while traing using tensor flow :

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I am getting this error while traing using tensor flow, would you mind helping me fixing this? Thank you a lot!

```
Exception in thread Thread-16923:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/aryan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner

    self.run()

  File "/home/aryan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run

    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)


  File "/home/aryan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn
/data_flow.py", line 240, in wait_for_threads

    self.coord.join(self.threads)

  File "/home/aryan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python
/training/coordinator.py", line 397, in join
    " ".join(stragglers))

"RuntimeError: Coordinator stopped with threads still running: Thread-16922"
```

Comment: col = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)  most probably this line of code if causing this error is there any way to use a bit of custom collection , i mean not this default_collection ..

Comment: how to stop any still running thread ,

Comment: join(<list of threads>): waits until the specified threads have stopped. // some threads failed to stop in this list